# Is it possible to reconcile jBPM 5.4 processes?

Tags: jbpm

is it possible to start a process v1 and at a point later deploy an updated version v2 of the the same process? 
What would happen to process instances of v1? Could they be switched easily to v2 or would they continue their life-cycle or would it fail?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the processes started with version 1 of the process will continue with that version until they are finished. When you deploy version 2, new instances will be created with that version. 
There are some situations where processes instances can be migrated from one version to the other, but most of the time that doesn't make sense from the business perspective.

Cheers